# Why cannot I use methods on brace-style macro expression in return position?

Tags: parsing, rust, macros

Consider the following example:

```rust
macro_rules! some {
    { $expr:expr } => { Some($expr) };
}

fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    some! {
        42
    }.map(std::convert::identity)
}
```

This code will fail to compile with the following error:

```
error: expected expression, found `.`
```

However, the compiler will accept the code if I bind the result to a temporary variable:

```rust
fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    let result = some! {
        42
    }.map(std::convert::identity);

    result
}
```

If I remove the invocation of `map` the code also compiles without issues:

```rust
fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    some! {
        42
    }
}
```

Parenthesis and bracket variants of macro invocation also work fine:

```rust
fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    some!(42).map(std::convert::identity)
}
```

```rust
fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
    some![42].map(std::convert::identity)
}
```

I presume there is some ambiguity when using curly braces but I don't exactly see what it can be. What is the problem here?

Comment: I believe this is because nearly everything is an expression in Rust. So when you bind the value using `let`, it become a statement expression and thus is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40100

There are several more macro parsing issues that may be interesting: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3AA-macros+label%3AA-parser